# Changing a system shortcut to exit fullscreen in MacOS

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

**Command+Control+F** is used to exit full screen in macOS, but its kinda difficult to press 3 buttons with the left hand for me. How can I change it t something easy, Command+E for eg.

I know there is an option to change shortcuts at **preferences>keyboard>shortcut**, but its confusing and I can't find 'full screen' listed there

Answer (score 3):

"Enter Full Screen" may not be a system-wide function, but most apps support it.

macOS has a builtin function to customize shortcut for applications. Open "System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> App Shortcuts". Bind <kbd>Command + E</kbd> to menu title "Enter Full Screen" for "All Applications". (<kbd>Command + E</kbd> is just taken as an example from what you referred in the question)

[image]

Then, bind <kbd>Command + E</kbd> to menu title "Exit Full Screen" as well, cause the menu title is changed as "Exit Full Screen" once you enter full screen.

Comment: It's not Chrome-specific at all, it's system-wide. Your solution would work if you changed that to All Applications -  see https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MzVa.png - I'd also strongly recommend **not** using something as potentially confusing as Cmd/E. Pick something with less potential for conflict.

Comment: @Tetsujin 1. No. The shortcut is chrome specific. Not all apps have a function support to enter/exit fullscreen. 2. The menu title change things has already been mentioned in my original answer. You may overlook it. 3. The Command+E is taken for example as what the questioner provided.

Comment: Points taken on 2 & 3 [I'd already realised 2 & edited my comment]. On point 1, no, it is, if not *absolutely* system-wide, in most apps as a menu item, so for it to work across all apps that already recognise the command, better to set to All Apps.

Comment: Additionally - & I'm uncertain as to whether this is truly global but works on everything I've tested so far - Esc is generally recognised as Exit Full Screen, though it doesn't appear as a menu item.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks. The answer is revised to bind the shortcut for "All Applications".